# Template Editor Script

Tags: templates, editor

Is it possible to find any open source template editors.. i wanted my site users to edit the contents of module as well as css. Once they click the edit, it should open a specific module or file name.. so the users can change the css and content and then click ok. Then after refresh the change in css and content should be reflected..

I am looking for something similar to the one in Wordpress Admin panel..where you can edit different files like header.php, style.css etc..

Any available scripts or demos or plugins or examples would be very helpful, as i can customize them to my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out the answer.. Some of them are

Bespin,
Ecoder
Ymacs
codemirror
emacs

they allow you to embed in your site.. and allow the users to edit the template of pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html editor like [fckeditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/) or [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and on server side save as php file and css file.
I on my site use JQuery rte editor and JSON RPC (Ajax -> PHP).

Comment: . i dont want a WYSIWYG Editor.. i want a normal code box which should allow some part of template to be edited like in wordpress... i want a plain text editor without rich text support..it should be able to edit a page in .php and stylesheet

Comment: Then just put textarea with html (you can add syntax highlighting), and when user click save, in server side replace css and part of the php with template from that textarea. You can alow users to put in template `<?=$header; ?>` for display header, which will be set in another part of the site from header input field.